# Desactivar/Activar la proteccion AVG antivirus mediante archivo BAT

Tags: archivo

Como dice el título, quiero saber como podría desactivar el Antivirus AVG mediante unas lineas de comandos BAT.
El problema viene de que tengo varios programas que si se encienden con el AVG activo, no funcionan. Si apago antes de iniciar el AVG, funcionan correctamente. La idea es tener un archivo BAT en lugar de el acceso directo común que directamente desactive el AVG durante un tiempo y luego ejecute la aplicación en cuestión.
Es posible realizar esto o seria más rápido desactivar el AVG manualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo entendido eso no es posible, por temas de seguridad necesitas deshabilitar manualmente un antivirus. Si el AVG te da problemas con algunos programas, te sugiero que los agregues a una lista de exclusión o cambies de antivirus.

Comment: Gracias, simplemente era eso, tenia esa pequeña fantasia XD